# Is there a Python equivalent to these functions?

Tags: python, jscript

This code coverts an Array Buffer to a String and vice versa

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an equivalent for these?  You don't have ArrayBuffers in Python.  Tell us what you are really trying to do, and we'll advise you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Python `bytearray()` can do the job.

u can refer this page for more info: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytearray